# Stains off of a glass top stove

Tags: cleaning, stove

I have tried a number of the solutions listed on my stove top to no avail.  The stains are white, like water stains & I can't figure out what they could be.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you possibly provide a picture?

Comment: I'm VTC as a duplicate, but I'd love to see it reopened if the OP returns and provides a picture. The other question doesn't have a picture either, we can't tell if it's actually the same kind of stain.